# Reload the same tab after performing an event?

Tags: jquery, url, tabs

I have a `form` with many `nav-tabs`. I am able to successfully get the same tab when user clicks on refresh or press `F5`. Following is my code:

```
// Store the currently selected tab in the hash value

$("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function(e) {
      var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
      window.location.hash = id;
});

// on load of the page: switch to the currently selected tab

 var hash = window.location.hash;
 $('#nav-tabs-wrapper a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
```

Now the problem is getting the same tab on `submit` on any other `event`.

```
$("#New").on("click", function () {

    $.ajax({
        success: function (result) {
        location.reload();
        }
   });

});
```

Now, on success I am trying to load the same location, but it is not working. It always take me to first tab.

Comment: can you share the html also ?

Comment: Did you solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use $.cookie to keep selected tab id

```
showTab();

$("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function(e) {
      var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
      window.location.hash = id;
      $.cookie("selectedTabId", hash);
      showTab();
});

function showTab()
{
    if($.cookie("selectedTabId") != null)
    {
       $('#nav-tabs-wrapper a[href="' + $.cookie("selectedTabId") + '"]').tab('show');
    }
    else
    {
       $('#nav-tabs-wrapper a[href="default"]').tab('show'); // show default
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the locaStorage for this.
when you are submitting the form store current tab id in localStorage like this:

```
$("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function(e) {
      var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
      window.location.hash = id;
      localStorage.setItem('tab',id);
});
```

Then read that localStorage key value when you come back after submitting the form.

```
$("#New").on("click", function () {

    $.ajax({
        success: function (result) {
        windlow.location = localStorage.getItem('tab');
        }
   });

});
```